# Python: manage multiple classes (from serialization) with common properties

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties, deserialization

I am new to structure Python projects, so please forgive any wrong approaches that could be written down here.

Two JSON schemes represent two objects. These are serialised into classes and have properties in common.

Example:

```
class TwoWheelVeicle(object):
    def __init__(self,v_family, v_subfamily):
        self.Family = v_family
        self.SubFamily = v_subfamily
        self.OtherProp = "other"

class FourWheelVeicle(object):
    def __init__(self,v_family):
        self.Family = v_family
        self.AnotherProp = "another"


def run_an_highway(vehicle):

    if isinstance(vehicle,FourWheelVeicle):
        return "Wrooom"

    if isinstance(vehicle,TwoWheelVeicle):
        if veichle.SubFamily in SubFams.NotAllowed:
            return "ALT!"
        else:
            return "Brooom" #forgive me for the sound


class SubFams(object):
    NotAllowed = ["Bicycle","50cc"]
    Known = ["200cc","Motorbike"]
```

I am quite unsure of the procedure overall:
- Shall I create an abstract parent class?
- Is `NotAllowed` stored correctly? This is due to the need of changing its content (that is serialized from some global parameter JSON, it's a #TODO)

..or simply I should not want to do any of these?

Lastly, the code does not allow for any checks if the properties that I serialize are correct (what if `SubFamily` is unknown? Should it be checked in the decoder?).

A big thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should abstract vehicle with a Vehicle class and then subclass it for your different vehicle types.

Your if chain isn't needed if your different subclasses have their own version for that same method.

Something in the line with these:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cc):
        self.name = name
        self.cc = cc
        self.wheels = None

    def runs_on_highway(self):
        return self.cc > 50

    def sound(self):
        pass

class TwoWheels(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, cc):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, name, cc)
        self.wheels = 2

    def sound(self):
        return 'Brooom.'

class FourWheels(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, cc):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, name, cc)
        self.wheels = 4

    def sound(self):
        return 'Vruuum'

class ElectricWheels(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, cc):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, name, 0)
        self.wheels = 4

    def runs_on_highway(self):
        return True

    def sound(self):
        return 'zzzzz.'

v1 = TwoWheels('Bicycle', 50)
v2 = FourWheels('Motorbike', 200)
v3 = ElectricWheels('ElectricBike', 0)

print(v1.runs_on_highway())
print(v2.runs_on_highway())
print(v3.runs_on_highway())

print(v1.name, v1.cc, v1.wheels, v1.sound())
print(v2.name, v2.cc, v2.wheels, v2.sound())
print(v3.name, v3.cc, v3.wheels, v3.sound())
```

Comment: You mean a getter for subFamily which returns None in `FourWheelsVehicles`? 
`if vehicle.get_SubFam() in SubFams.NotAllowed` should perform what above.
And.. what about `NotAllowed`?

Comment: No @C.Claudio, I was thinking you can explore a class arrangement like what I have just posted.